# sputtering , my 98 s 10 2.2 is sputtering in low rpm still after changing fuel filter,plugs,wires and a craked exhaust manifold

Tags: engine, chevrolet, s10

from the begining is that my exhausts manifold cracked and later it started loosing power to a point that it die and i started it again. . i change the fuel filter and started right up but it began sputtering and me keeping it in high idle to back it into the garage. i change plugs wires and a new exhaust manifold, the fuel pump was change about 2 years ago,what are the chances of going bad again i do not know,maybe is not sending enough psi,i need help also i forgot to mention that i replace the 02 sensor. thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When you replaced the exhaust manifolds and the O2 sensors, did you reset the computer? This may help your situation out quite dramatically.